# Adding a year to database time column with an input method

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to add 1 to 2 years onto a membership duration (time). I can edit the dates and save them to the database.

What I am trying to do is have an input that recognizes 1 or 2. If the post  column `memduration` is 1 or 2 the respective amount of years should be added to the date.

Here is my code, I have the times set up but i can't add the time. I can edit the time fields, just not negotiate the difference.

```
if($_POST['MemDuration'] == "2") {
    $MemDuration = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('+2 year', $Renewdate));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
if((int)$_POST['MemDuration']) {
    $MemDuration = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('+'.(int)$_POST['MemDuration'].' years', $Renewdate));
}
```

Keep in mind `$Renewdate` should be a valid timestamp (integer), if it is not - pass it through `strtotime`.

EDIT: after the comments I believe what you need is this:

```
if((int)$_POST['MemDuration']) {
    $MemDuration = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('+'.(int)$_POST['MemDuration'].' years', strtotime($Renewdate)));
}
```

Comment: The database datatype is set to date. no specific length. this is my input field.. still no luck.. cheers so far                                                                              value="<?php echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime($row_rsMember['Renewdate']));?>" <?php if($_SESSION['ocTemplate_UserGroup'] <= 9){ ?> disabled="disabled" <?php } ?> /></td>